# facebook publish stream

Tags: php, facebook, api, sdk, stream

i have problem... I did follow [this site](http://www.moskjis.com/other-platforms/publish-facebook-page-wall-from-your-site)... Im not good at facebook API.. sorry im really noobs with API..

my code:

```
<?php


define('FB_APIKEY', '***************************');
define('FB_SECRET', '***************************');
define('FB_SESSION', '***************************');

require_once 'facebook-platform/php/facebook.php';

echo "post on wall";
echo "<br/>";

try {
 $facebook = new Facebook(FB_APIKEY, FB_SECRET);
 $facebook->api_client->session_key = FB_SESSION;
 $facebook->api_client->expires = 0;
 $message = 'testasdfsadf';

 $attachment = array(
 'name' => $_POST["name"],
 'href' => $_POST["href"],
 'description' => $_POST["description"],
 'media' => array(array('type' => 'image',
 'src' => $_POST["src"],
 'href' => $_POST["href"])));

 $action_links = array( array('text' => 'TITLE', 'href' => 'http://www.mysite.com'));

 $attachment = json_encode($attachment);
 $action_links = json_encode($action_links);

 $target_id = "2410160********";
 $session_key = FB_SESSION;


     if( $facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message, $attachment, $action_links, null, $target_id)) {
     echo "Added on FB Wall";
     }
     } catch(Exception $e) {
     echo $e . "<br />";
     }
?>
```

I got error:

```
post on wall
exception 'FacebookRestClientException' with message 'The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action' in /Users/*****/Sites/FacebookTEST/facebook-platform/php/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php:3025 Stack trace: #0 /Users/******/Sites/FacebookTEST/facebook-platform/php/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php(916): FacebookRestClient->call_method('facebook.stream...', Array) #1 /Users/******/Sites/FacebookTEST/index.php(46): FacebookRestClient->stream_publish('testasdfsadf', '{"name":null,"h...', '[{"text":"TITLE...', NULL, '2410160********') #2 {main}
```

Comment: Did you follow the step entitled "Give permission (for application) to publish on your wall" ?

Comment: yep i found answer...use link to authorize..

Comment: This article is really **REALLY** old! Try checking the [latest](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) SDK then add the code in my [article](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-a-message-on-the-user-wall-using-facebook-graph-api/33/) to the [example.php](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) of the SDK.

Comment: yeah but im using old version =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer:

here solution:
http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permissions.php?api_key=**YOUR_API_KEY**&v=1.0&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?xxRESULTTOKENxx&display=page&ext_perm=publish_stream,offline_access&enable_profile_selector=1&profile_selector_ids=**ID_OF_YOUR_PAGE**

Insert your API Key and Page ID in BOLD text..